# ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 123 as codeigniter active records query?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2

How to execute

```
ALTER TABLE tblname AUTO_INCREMENT = 123
```

as codeigniter active records query?

There is something called dbforge->modify_column() in codeigniter , do i have to use that, if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->db->query('ALTER TABLE tbl_name AUTO_INCREMENT 1');`  is working for me.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$this->db->query("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT 1");
```

change value after **`AUTO_INCREMENT`** where you want to start auto increment value from like this

```
$this->db->query("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT 12");
```

Alter table operation called **DDL** Data Defination Language where you execute queries at database not at data.

Comment: This is the answer to the OP's question, since he specifically asked if it's possible to start in a different index. The MySQL `ALTER` command receives a _start value_ when `AUTO_INCREMENT` is used, therefore we can do things like this sequentially: `$this->db->delete('mytable', ['id >', 3]); $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT 4');`.